# Auto Action when UITextfield goes empty

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, ios6

Hey guys i am trying to launch an event when an UITextView goes empty. I am having a problem that how to trigger an action when textview goes empty. I mean whenever UITextView goes empty following func will pe performed

```
 -(void)textViewIsEmpty
 {
      NSLog(@"Text View Is Empty");
 }
```

I am having problem in order to automatically detect that textView is empty now.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **textFieldDidEndEditing** delegate method.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if([textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                                        withString:@""].length >0)
      NSLog(@"Text Field Is Empty");
      //or perform selector textFieldIsEmpty
}
```

**Add** an **notification** observer for **UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification** name:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(textFieldChanged:)
                                         name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                       object:self.yourTextField];
```

selector will be like this:

```
-(void)textFieldChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    UITextField *txt = (UITextField *)[notification object];
     if([txt.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                                        withString:@""].length >0)
      NSLog(@"Text Field Is Empty");
}
```

**EDIT :** Remove notification when not needed:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: hey thanks i used samething for text view and it worked out for me thanks again :)

Comment: i did but it says not enough repu so when i will get enough repo i will tick for sure :)

Answer (score 2):

Things might have changed since this question was asked, but I wanted to contribute my answer since I was working on something similar.

Since Xcode 5, you only really need to create a method and associate it with the `Editing Changed` Sent Event.

In my class, I created a method that returned an `IBAction`:

```
- (IBAction)priceFieldEdited:(id)sender {
    [self refreshFetchedResultsAndTable];
}
```

Then, all I needed to do was right-click dragged to the class and select the method.

[image: Example of associating the text field to the method in the class.]

Answer (score 1):

Add an notification observer for `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` name:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(textFieldDidChanged:)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                           object:self.yourTextField];
```

`textFieldDidChanged:` is a custom method to manage the action when textfield did change. You can judge the length of your textfield there.

---

EDIT:

Sample code for `textFieldDidChanged:`:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
  if (self.yourTextField.length)
    return;
  [self textFieldIsEmpty];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSRange textFieldRange = NSMakeRange(0, [textField.text length]);
    if (NSEqualRanges(range, textFieldRange) && [string length] == 0) {
        // Game on: when you return YES from this, your field will be empty
    }
    return YES;
}
```

It's useful to note that the field won't be empty until after this method returns, so you might want to set some intermediate state here, then use `textFieldDidEndEditing:` to know that the user is done emptying out the field.

You can also add this to `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;`

Comment: Brother Sorry to mention that i am using UITextView not UITextField. I did the mistake. Can you please help me out with textview please. I am  also going to correct my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"RETURN ON KEYBORAD - PRESSED");

    if ( ([ textField.text length ] == 0) | ([[textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] ] length]  == 0))
    {
        [self textFieldIsEmpty];
        return YES;
    }
}
```